# Нужна ли запятая в данном предложении перед вторым союзом в "и летом и зимой"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

Начался один из тех штормов, которые бывают на Каспии и летом и зимой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Начался один из тех штормов, которые бывают на Каспии и летом и зимой.***

Запятая не нужна, так как члены "и летом и зимой" образуют тесное смысловое единство.

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/43.htm#%D0%B7_05

В вашем примере слова "и летом и зимой" подчёркивают частотность штормов на Каспии. Их косвенно можно заменить одним словом "постоянно", это не два независимых друг от друга члена, а цельное, единое сочетание — и поэтому оно нерасчленимо.

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

> ...А солдат безвылазно и летом и зимой сидел в голой дикой степи и караулил ветер.
>
> Купил прекрасную шляпу за двадцатку, можно ходить в ней и летом и зимой.

Comment: Я просмотрела полный текст и считаю, что здесь сочетание действительно имеет значение "всегда, постоянно, в любое время", так что ответ верен.С другой стороны, в Нацкорпусе есть примеры и  с запятой. Там обобщения нет, называются два времени года, а перечислительная интонация вполне уместна. Например: Турбазы принимают туристов и летом, и зимой. Байкал популярен у российских и зарубежных туристов и летом, и зимой.  Сравнить: Я использовал погружной насос,  который успешно работает и летом и зимой.